# EPSON WF-2630 printer working fine but screen not showing anything

Tags: epson-workforce

My EPSON printer is functioning properly however the screen is not showing anything words or symbols on it, it is lit up as if it should have writing on it however it doesn't. This is turning out to be very annoying as It is giving the sound as though the printer is low on ink, and so won't print anything, however I can't tell which ink it is that is low or even manage to get to change the ink as you do this through the screen! Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if your printer has gone bad. Try completely removing power from the unit and rebooting it. I doubt that will help, but it is worth a shot. Is it less than a year old? Check on a warranty if so.

You can do most operations from the Windows software. The screen is not needed. Please see the online manual about this: https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd4/cpd40876/index.html

Specifically, you do not need the screen to change an ink cartridge and you can check the status of your supplies through Windows.

This printer is listed at $80 retail and on sale for $60. That's probably cheaper than it costs to buy a set of ink cartridges. So, don't waste too much time on this unit. It's unfortunate, but ink jets are designed to fail. They are wasteful, have a finite life (due to dumping ink in the bottom of the printer), and are extremely expensive to operate - a money making racket for the manufacturers.